# Multiple legends for barCharts

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

I came across [this](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/legends/include-multiple-legends.html) and found it quite cool.

Here is the minimal example:

```
 Plot3D[
   Re[Sin[x + I y]], 
   {x, -2 Pi, Pi},
   {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
   PlotLegends -> {
     Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0.3]}], Right], 
     Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0.3]}], Top]
   }
]
```

I want to do the same for a BarChart and do the equivalent of:

```
BarChart[
  {1,2,10,20},
  ChartStyle -> {Red,Blue, Darker[Red], Darker[Blue]},
  ChartLegends-> {
    Placed[{"One", "Two"}, Top],
    Placed[{"One", "Two", "Ten", "Twenty"}, Left]
  }
]
```

However the above simply gives me one legend with the last set of values. what am I missing? is there an elegant way of getting it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use two datasets as input:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 10, 20}, {}}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Red], Darker[Blue]}, 
  ChartLegends -> 
    {Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"One", "Two"}], Top],
     Placed[{"One", "Two", "Ten", "Twenty"}, Left]}]
```

[image]

Another way is to wrap input data with `Legended`

```
BarChart[MapThread[Legended[#, Placed[#2, Left]] &, 
     {{1, 2, 10, 20}, {"One", "Two", "Ten", "Twenty"}}], 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Red], Darker[Blue]}, 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[{"One", "Two"}, Top]]
```

[image]

Use `ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"` to get

[image]

The first method requires manual insertion of appropriate colors in the first `SwatchLegend` to get the same picture, i.e., to use

```
 ChartLegends -> {Placed[SwatchLegend[ColorData[{"Rainbow",{1,4}}]/@{1,2}, 
    {"One", "Two"}], Top], 
  Placed[{"One", "Two", "Ten", "Twenty"}, Left]}
```